Does watch in react hook form cause re-render?
I have just started using watch with react hook form. Just need a n information whether the component gets re-rendered upon every change? If it does then how is it better than using traditional onchange and setstate in forms.
I have tried getting relevant information but the answers I got was not satisfactory.

Try to add console.log("Rerenders") as the first line in your component.
